# XSLT to change the structure of the Schema

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm new to XSLT, looking for a schema change using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0

Source XML:

```
<ABC>
<AB>
    <A>
        <String>123</String>
        <Valid>true</Valid>
    </A>
    <B>
        <String/>
        <Valid>false</Valid>
    </B>
    <C>
        <Int64>12345</Int64>
        <Valid>true</Valid>
    </C>
    <D>
        <String>1234567</String>
        <Valid>true</Valid>
    </D>
</AB>
```

'

Target XML:

```
<ABC>
    <AB>
        <A>123></A>
        </B> 
        <C>12345</C>
        <D>1234567</D>
    </AB>
</ABC>
```

Please note: `<AB>` is a repeating element. Please help me to figure out the issue.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>    
<xsl:template match="/">
   <ABC>
        <AB>
           <A><xsl:value-of select="String"/></A>
           <B><xsl:value-of select="String"/></B>
           <C><xsl:value-of select="Int64"/></C> 
         </AB>
    </ABC>
</xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the sample XSLT i wrote. It is able to create the schema but not able to insert the value

Comment: Where do you think the "67" from <D> is coming from?

Comment: sorry its is a typo in the input.. the value is "1234567"

Comment: You should at least provide a pseudo-algorithm to understand how one goes from input to output xml. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask a correct question. Thanks

Comment: @baptistemm I'm sorry, the requirement is that.. I'm getting the source XML in a xmlstring, in order to map to the downstream system, i need to convert the source xml to the target xml for mapping purpose.

Comment: I understand its not the code writing service. All i'm asking is about suggestion or approach. not exact XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an XML -> XML transformation where you want to preserve part of the structure and the nodes then you usually start writing the transformation with the identity transformation, in XSLT 3 you can do that by declaring `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#built-in-templates-shallow-copy), in earlier versions you spell it out by using the template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

in your stylesheet, then you only need to add templates for the nodes you want to transform, in your case it seems you simply want to transform all child elements of `AB` elements by using the string value of the first child element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="AB/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="*[1]"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJw is an online example.

Of course depending on your needs or exact requirements you can write other or more specific templates e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="AB/C">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="Int64"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not too tough. Actually you XPath not reach to print the values. You may go for below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AB">
            <AB>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:value-of select="*[1]"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </AB>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```